# PHP - Check that value doesn't appear twice in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array inside my PHP app that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name1
            [language] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name2
            [language] => 1
        )

)
```

How can I check that "language" with value 1 doesnt appear twice, as effectively as possible?

Comment: If possible, prevent dupes when creating the array, saves you a step.

Comment: Hi Alec, How would you suggest doing that?

Comment: Depends on how the array is created. If the source of the information is a database, make sure to only to select distinct language IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$dupe = 0;
foreach($yourarray as $key => $val) {
    if(array_key_exists($seen, $val['language'])) {
        // a duplicate exists!
        $dupe = 1;
        // could do other stuff here too if you want,
        // like if you want to know the $key with the dupe

        // if all you care about is whether or not any dupes
        // exist, you could use a "break;" here to early-exit
        // for efficiency. To find all dupes, don't use break.
    }
    $seen[$val['language']] = 1;
}

// If $dupe still = 0 here, then no duplicates exist.
```

Comment: Either a `break` if only wanting to see if *any* dupes exist, or some other code if desired (for instance, one might want to find all of the dupes and record their positions, et cetera - I'm keeping this example general).

Comment: Hi Dav, thanks a lot. Do you think that it would be wiser to use ISSET instead of array_key_exist to save performance? Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: `array_key_exists` is the proper tool for the job - it *that* much slower than `isset` and is more readable in general.

Comment: fun fact: dupe in the polish language means ass

Answer (score 1):

Tried the PHP function [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)?

(Read the comments/user contributed notes below, especially the one by *regeda at inbox dot ru*, who made a recursive function for multi-dimensional arrays)